# Get header info Android/NodeJS

Tags: android, node.js

I've created an API in NodeJS that contains headers (which are the tokens).

**The volley library (ANDROID) post goes like this:**

```
RequestQueue queue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,REGISTERUSERURL,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        System.out.println(response);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                      hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                }) {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email","myname@gmail.com");
                params.put("password", "myname");
                return params;
            };
        };
        queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

But this doesnt register from the server-side. Whats the issue?

Comment: Could you please clarify what 'register' means here?

Comment: https://www.kompulsa.com/how-to-send-a-post-request-in-android/

Comment: then against that url make get method with express in node.js

Comment: http://envyandroid.com/android-volley-empty-parameters/